# Responsive form that switches between 1 or 2 controls per line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a responsive form using Bootstrap.

When the page is of `medium` width or larger, I would like the date range controls to share the same line:

[image: Web form controls where the last two controls are on the same line]

---

When the page is small, I would like the two date controls to be placed on separate lines:

[image]

The problem is - if I put the `Start` and `End` in the same form group, it doesn't space well when on separate lines:

[image]

---

But then, if I put the `Start` and `End` in different form groups, they are always on separate lines, even when the screen is wide.

Does bootstrap provide a way to deal with this, or am I going to have to write my own custom styling rules?

Here is the complete code as a plunk:

http://plnkr.co/edit/XZYEU73ov7BBaMQmO7ec?p=preview

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
          Video
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2  control-label">
          Start
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-4">
          <input class="form-control" type="date" />
        </div>
        <!-- If I start a new form group here, it forces a new line -->
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
          End
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-4">
          <input class="form-control" type="date" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
      <button class="btn btn-primary">
        Generate Report
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: media queries would be one way, but i'm sure you've tried that and don't want it?

Comment: @Satej S - The bootstrap framework which this is based upon already uses media queries.  This question isn't about the basic mechanics - it's about getting the vertical spacing exactly right.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a custom CSS class and add it too the one you want the margin under (change max width as appropriate).

```
@media all and (max-width: 991px){
    .margin-bottom {
      margin-bottom:15px;
    }
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/kZza07SVcYa6QfC8YwpU?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Example 1 in http://plnkr.co/edit/XZYEU73ov7BBaMQmO7ec?p=preview, use the following CSS for responsive View :

```
@media all and (max-width: 991px){

.col-sm-10{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
 }

}
```

Comment: OK, I just tried that. When it switches to one-control-per-line, there is now twice as much space below the Video row.